# Serving Static Files from JavaEE project on Tomcat on EC2

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I created a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse, exported it to a .war file, and I'm running the .war file in an Amazon EC2 instance (Ubuntu 14.04) with Tomcat installed. It works fine if I just use a PrintWriter to do output, but I want to serve a simple index.html file when the URL "someEC2path.amazonaws.com/myapp/index.html" is requested.

Inside my project, I have a WebContents folder that contains 3 other folders: META-INF, WEB-INF, and static. I put my index.html file in the static folder. Inside my web.xml file, I have two servlet-mappings which maps url-pattern /* to servlet-name "myapp" and url-pattern *.html to servlet-name "default".

I did this because I read in multiple places this was how Tomcat will get static files. It isn't working. My index.html file is not being sent to the browser. How do I get Tomcat to find/send my index.html file when the URL listed above is called?

Comment: Don't map html files to servlets.  Just put them in WEB-INF.

Comment: On AWS, you can also use an S3 bucket to put all of your static content and map it to a sub domain such as static.mydomainname.com. See this doc... https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html

Answer (score 0):

The solution was determining the servlet context path to determine the actual location of index.html. I ran this code:
    ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
    String contextPath = servletContext.getRealPath(File.separator);
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println(contextPath);
Then I found out the full location of index.html and was able to reference it properly in my servlet.